# How to switch code from db class to Eloquent query? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want from the DB class to switch to Eloquent and I have a few of queries

This is first, I want to insert  in subscription_user user_id of user and hard core subscription_id = 1 as default.

```
    DB::table('subscription_user')->insert(
            ['user_id' => $user->id, 'subscription_id' => 1]
        );
```

Second, I want to return verification token

```
     $check = DB::table('user_verifications')->where('token', 
     $verification_code)->first();
```

Third, I want to update accepted field

```
       $res =   DB::table('offers')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(['accepted' => 1]);
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? Isn't clear what are you asking at the moment. If you need help doing it check this useful guide: [ask].

Comment: Oh I think I got it, you want to do those operations using Eloquent right?

Comment: @hck Yes,   I want to transfer this to the eloquent code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## #1

> ```
> DB::table('subscription_user')->insert(
>         ['user_id' => $user->id, 'subscription_id' => 1]
>     );
> ```

Eloquent equivalent (*):

```
$subscriptionUser = SubscriptionUser
                        ::create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'subscription_id' => 1]);
```

In case this comes from a many-to-many relationship between the models `Subscription` and `User` you could just do (**):

```
Subscription::find(1)->users()->attach($user->id);
```

## #2

> ```
> $check = DB::table('user_verifications')->where('token', 
> $verification_code)->first();
> ```

Eloquent equivalent (***):

```
$check = UserVerification::where('token', $verification_code)->first();
```

## #3

> ```
> $res = DB::table('offers')
>     ->where('id', $id)
>     ->update(['accepted' => 1]);
> ```

Eloquent equivalent:

```
$res = Offer::find($id)->update(['accepted' => 1]); // this will return a boolean.
$offer = Offer::find($id); // this will get the updated record.
```

---

(*) In order for this to work you need a Eloquent model called `SubscriptionUser` with the table property set to: `'subscription_user'`.

(**) In order for this to work you need to [set the relationship in the models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

(***) In order for this to work you need a Eloquent model called `UserVerification` with the table property set to: `'user_verifications'`.

Comment: I've linked this all and everything is working for now. Now I'm going to switch to the eloquent and let me know if it works for me

Comment: do I have to change the name of the model to do this eloquent?

Comment: @AlexAl no, those are just model that I figure it out from your code, you could use any model name that you want, just make sure to config the `$table` and also `$primmaryKey` propperties if you wont follow the Eloquent conventions. Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) of the documentations to know more of the model conventions.

Comment: All my users are registered in the database and they return my error " Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'devcars.subscription_users' doesn't exist"

Comment: Okay now work but  I must add in model 
    protected $table = 'subscription_user';
    public $timestamps = false;
Thank you but why i need set protected $table ?

Comment: The default convention in laravel for a model (in singular) is to look up for a table with name of the plural version of the model. For example if model `Role` it will look up for `roles` table. If you want to use a different table name, you need to specify it. the same goes for PK. Laravel will assume that your primmary key is the column `id`, but if you use a different one (for example `role_id`) you need to specify it. There are a lot of parameter to be configured in the model, Laravel is very flexible.

Comment: Vote up for you